# freeGLUT - Moving camera with mouse?

Tags: windows, mingw, codeblocks, freeglut

So, here I am again. How exactly do I get the freeGLUT camera to rotate with the mouse (without being dragged)? I've got the simple concepts down:

1. Move the mouse back to the middle of the window when moved. Because the user runs out of window without this, so the camera doesn't move when the cursor is out of the window.
2. Use `glutPassiveMotionFunc()` to utilize the mouse movement.

Any ideas on how the heck to do this? I cannot find any examples that **don't** require the user to click & drag to move the camera.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect: you want to distinguish mouse motion to move camera and mouse motion just bringing back to the center, isn't it ? how distinguishing, if not by a mouse button ?

Or do you simply want to have small mouse motion making big camera rotation so that the user never go far to screen center ?